# Cloned mac address not working with kernel 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Tags: networking, kernel

After updating from 4.13.0-37 to 4.13.0-38 (Ubuntu 16.04), the Ethernet connection does not work anymore if (and only if) I want to use a cloned MAC address. The same kind of repeating message occurs:

> e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down

When I goes back to 4.13.0-37, everything is back to normal: I can use cloned mac address again.

Comment: it's not very clear what is your problem. what do you mean by clone mac address ?

Comment: @Kiwy It's a standard terminology. Do not use the one of the network card. Google the word. Some people need to do that for security reason.

Comment: @Kiwy I chose nothing. Ubuntu did for me. I tried the other network card of my motherboard (gigabyte GA-H270N-WIFI), Ubuntu chooses for me the driver 'igb'. And now the mac address cloning is working just fine.

Comment: Sorry e1000 is often use as default virtual network card and this firmware is usually not recommanded by any virtualisation solution but it works on almost every OS. I though your ubuntu was a VM.

Comment: @Kiwy I know nothing about the kernel development. Therefore, I won't file a bug report. Someone else knowing the subject could do that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the issue can be solved by not using the Ubuntu default network manager. Just adding the interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` solves the issue:

```
#auto lo  
#iface lo inet loopback 

auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp  
hwaddress ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. Since I have two different network cards on my motherboard, I'll use the other one. Hopefully your fix will work for other people.

Comment: @Philippe, I do not see why. I also have two network cards. Your card can be identified with eth0. Make a udev rule to rename your enp0s31f6 to eth0

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same problem as described here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1525523

And which was fixed here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198047

I'm not 100% sure though as the kernel version in the bug report is said to be 4.14.3. But the description sounds very much the same.